# detect which image is on scrollview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

help me PLEASE, to detect which Image is on scrollview when I scroll it.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
NSArray *colors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"ip1.jpg", @"ip2.jpg", @"ip3.jpg", @"ip4.jpg", @"ip5.jpg", @"ip6.jpg", @"ip7.jpg", @"ip8.jpg", @"ip9.jpg", @"ip10.jpg",@"ip11.jpg",@"ip12.jpg",@"ip13.jpg",@"ip14.jpg",@"ip15.jpg",@"ip16.jpg",@"ip17.jpg",@"ip18.jpg",@"ip19.jpg",@"ip20.jpg",@"ip21.jpg", nil];

    NSMutableArray *imgArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    UIImageView *tempImageView;
    for(NSString *name in colors) {
        tempImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        tempImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
        tempImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:name];
        [imgArray addObject:tempImageView];

    }

    CGSize pageSize = scrollView.frame.size; // scrollView is an IBOutlet for our UIScrollView
    NSUInteger page = 0;
    for(prevView in imgArray) {

        [scrollView addSubview:prevView];


        // This is the important line
        prevView.frame = CGRectMake(pageSize.width * page++ + 30, 0, pageSize.width - 60, pageSize.height);
 }   




    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(pageSize.width * [imgArray count], pageSize.height);

}



- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender {
    if (!pageControlBeingUsed) {
        // Switch the indicator when more than 50% of the previous/next page is visible
        CGFloat pageWidth = self.scrollView.frame.size.width;
        int page = floor((self.scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
        self.pageControl.currentPage = page;



    }
}
```

Help me please. If i use slog to show CurrentPage, it shows me like "117892", I just Need a NSLog that will show me current image from my "colors" NSArray. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,you can declare "page" variable as global then pass as shown in the code

```
NSLog(@"%@",[colors objectAtIndex:page]);
```

Comment: 2012-12-08 04:22:57.761 MyProject[2948:f803] ip1.jpg
2012-12-08 04:22:57.804 MyProject[2948:f803] ip1.jpg
2012-12-08 04:22:57.812 MyProject[2948:f803] ip1.jpg
2012-12-08 04:22:57.826 MyProject[2948:f803] ip1.jpg
2012-12-08 04:22:57.842 MyProject[2948:f803] ip1.jpg
2012-12-08 04:22:57.867 MyProject[2948:f803] ip1.jpg
2012-12-08 04:22:57.892 MyProject[2948:f803] ip1.jpg
2012-12-08 04:22:57.907 MyProject[2948:f803] ip2.jpg
Why It show like that? :( How can i fix it?

Comment: assuming the pages are calculated correctly that should do nicely in the didScroll function

Comment: - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender {
 if (!pageControlBeingUsed) {
  // Switch the indicator when more than 50% of the previous/next page is visible
  CGFloat pageWidth = self.scrollView.frame.size.width;
  int page = floor((self.scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
  self.pageControl.currentPage = page;
        NSLog(@"%@",[colors objectAtIndex:pageControl.currentPage]);
 }
}

Comment: I pasted in "scrollViewDidScroll", objectAtIndex:page I tried, but also shows me repeated lines as nslog.